# How to Create instance of a type that is in the EntryAssembly

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-assembly, activator

I have a .dll file that I want to import into my projects and below is a class that belongs to the .dll

I'm able to get the name of the DbContext of the solution but in the next line 
when I try to get type of it, it is null. It's understandable as the desired type does not exist in that solution. but is it possible to create the type and instance in this case?

any help is very appreciated, thanks!

```
static class EntityBase
{
public static DbContext MyCreateNewDbContextInstance()
    {
        string myDbContextName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().DefinedTypes
            .Where(t => typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList().First().FullName;

        Type type = Type.GetType(myDbContextName);

        var context = Activator.CreateInstance(type, false);

        return (DbContext)context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove `.FullName`, you already have that type. `Type type = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().DefinedTypes.First(t => typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(t))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than retrieving the type, and then re-retrieving it from name, you could grab the `Type` object with your initial LINQ query:

```
Type type = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
    .DefinedTypes
    .Where(t => typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .FirstOrDefault();
object res = null;
if (type != null) {
    res = Activator.CreateInstance(type, false);
}
return (DbContext)res;
```